# 200 amp Service failed inspection questions

Tags: electrical, electrical-panel

My inspector failed the inspection as he said:

- the service conductors are too small
- need main outside
- no unfused conductor behind wall.

My electrician says he has never installed a main outside. The 200 amp panel inside the room has required disconnect. Is he right? Is a 200 amp disconnect required outside per electrical code or any other remedy?

What does "no unfused conductor behind wall" mean?

Also, what is the wire gauge required on a 200 amp service?

Comment: The outside disconnect requirement might be a fire department regulation, more than electrical code.  Do not know the wire gauge requirement, but should be known by your electrician.  Distance does play a part on what gauge is needed, but that is also in the tables.  Infused conductor might be a conductor that had too much to drink.

Comment: You sure he didn't say "*un*fused conductor" - in other words a "conductor not protected by a fuse" (or other means of over-current protection)?

Comment: Everywhere I’ve lived required an external disconnect so emergency folks can kill power to the building without entering it. Sounds like your electrician messed up. We’re they licensed and bonded?

Comment: Was this new construction or a panel upgrade/change out?  Was meter can replaced?

Comment: Are you in Canada or US? Don’t need the the outside main disconnect in Canada.

Comment: LOL that's pretty horrible to fail on *wire size* LOL.  Is this person totally incompetent, or is this property actually *not a dwelling*? Because the 83% derate Ed mentioned only applies to dwellings, not commercial/farm.

Comment: The service conductor size should be standard - hard to believe a locally licensed electrician would get that wrong. As far as main outside, that is very much subject to local requirements as it is in the latest NEC but many jurisdictions have not adopted that yet *or* have made exceptions. I am (hopefully soon) getting a heavy-up done and my electrician has been in contact (numerous times) with AHJ to make sure he gets the details right as they have changed over time *and* some details (in my case, allowed meter cans) have been changed due to supply issues.  **It is the electrician's job to**

Comment: **get these details right!** About the only part that should be on the homeowner is you have stuff in the required panel workspace area. Everything else should be entirely the electrician's job. Especially service wires, disconnect, etc. as homeowner (in most places) doesn't get to touch that anyway.

Comment: With the way the violation was worded their is no main outside the 2020 requirement was adopted OR service entrance wires are not in conduit to the main panel inside a wall, I can’t believe how many times I have heard “my electrician “ then multiple code failures, where the friend helping was a LME or a LEA sure they are electricians but neither can update a service and one can not work on a panel at all!!! but the home owner can in my jurisdiction, The homeowner thought the person had knowledge because of a lower level License, this is probably one of those cases.

Answer (score 3):

The NEC updated the requirement for a main disconnect outside in the 2020 revision,.

prior to this the conductors had to be in conduit if they entered the building with no disconnect but jump back to the first sentence.

The size of the conductor is contingent on the type of wire copper or aluminum. Code allows the feeder to be 83% of the table size.

so 2/0 copper and 4/0 aluminum would be sufficiently large enough 75 degree Column of table 310.15.b.16.

So if your wire was smaller the inspector was correct again and yes it is a NEC code requirement for the disconnect (or main) to be outside the structure. So with the info provided the inspector is correct.

Comment: I am guessing the disconnect on top of the hydro pole does not count anymore?

Comment: The disconnect on the pole has never counted that is the utility disconnect or the line fuses up on the pole. The rare exception would be “ag or farm” property that has a home but a commercial disconnect accessible at ground level (rare).

Comment: @crip659 is the disconnect on top of the hydro pole something your wife or teenager would easily throw in an emergency?  Is it like a box at 4-5' height on the pole that says "Main Disconnect" with a handle sticking out of the side?  (I don't care if the handle simply shoves/pulls a fiberglass rod going up to the top of the pole).